# How do I combine data from multiple rows in excel to one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel - columns to one cell](https://superuser.com/questions/404148/excel-columns-to-one-cell)

I have a list of product skus in one column in excel. I have thousands of these skus that need to be combined in one cell separated by commas with no spaces. There are too many rows of data to use the concatenate function. Not sure how to get this done. Here's an example of what I'm working with but with 6,000+ more rows. I'm using Excel 2003.

```
A
140-12
1074-156
903-78
876-65
349-09
986-43
237-12
342-11
450-187
677-133
```

Comment: Pretty sure there's a limit to the number of characters per cell in Excel. I can safely say what you are trying to do will exceed that limit. You can try to export it to a CSV file and edit that with Notepad++ to achieve your desired result but I doubt excel will import that into one cell.

Comment: Yes, according to [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) even Excel 2010 has a 32,767 character limit on the total number of characters that a cell can contain.

Comment: You may have luck with some of the answers in this question. http://superuser.com/q/404148/143655

Answer (score 2):

Bearing in mind the other answers about the cell character limit, do you want to just output a text file with the format as required? If you do, I would export to CSV, then use a text editor: Vim on Windows will be quickest, but probably the least intuitive.

Open the file in Vim and then type `:%s/\n/,/g` and hit enter. All newlines will be replaced with commas. File > Save and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, even if you do this with a VB macro, according to [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) even Excel 2010 has a 32,767 character limit on the total number of characters that a cell can contain.

With 6000 rows this would only allow an average of 5 characters per SKU.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with creating your own functions in VB code, there is a [StringConcat function shown here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx) that may meet your needs.

> Concatenating text in a range of cells:
>
> =StringConcat("|",B1:B5)
>
> returns the values from B1:B5, each separated by a | character.

Of course, you'll still need to watch the character limitation of 32,767 which I think you're going to hit.